# Optimisation: (\\[abc] | [^abc])*

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long Regex (JavaScript), and it contains the following construct:

```
((\\\\)|(\\[abc])|([^abc]))*
```

**The regex says:**

Match any String, that doesn't contain the letters a,b and c.

In except if they're escaped by a backslash.

If the backslash is escaped (eg. `\\a`), also don't match these letters.

**Here's a simple match-example:**

`eee`a`e`a`ee\aee\\\\`a`e\\\\\aee`

I wonder if it's possible to optimise this regulat expression. This is only a little example, the actual regex I'm using is bigger, and I have lots of code twice.

Comment: I am a little confused to what you want to really do here.

Comment: @hwnd I have a tokenizer, which should split a text into different tokens. And if there're special symbols between word characters, they belong to a seperate token - as long as they aren't escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a more logical (and likely faster) regexp would be something like:

```
(?:[^abc\\]|\\.)*
```

In other words, a backslash will escape *anything*, including another backslash.

Note a few things: first, if you don't need to capture parts of the match, use non-capturing groups. That buys you a little performance. Second, when there are multiple alternatives, put the most common one first.

You might get even better performance this way (try it):

```
[^abc\\]*(?:\\.[^abc\\]*)*
```

Rather than going through the alternation for each and every character, that will "eat" runs of non-special characters with a single step. Nested `*` can be bad news, leading to quadratic (or worse) runtime in cases where the regex doesn't match, but in this case that won't happen.

When writing this answer, I discovered that JS's regex engine has no possessive matchers. That sucks -- you could get better worst-case performance if they were available. (An important tip for working towards regex mastery: when performance testing a regex, always test cases where it does match AND where it doesn't match. The worst-case performance generally occurs when it doesn't.)

Comment: How exacly does ++ and *+ work? I think they aren't avaiable in Javascript

Comment: @maja, looks like you're right. That sucks. Because putting a `+` on the first branch of the alternation could improve your performance in cases where the regex matches, but without possessive matchers, it could also lead to very bad performance when the regex doesn't match.

Comment: @maja, I came up with another option which may be faster. Give it a try. Please note that if you don't know what you are doing, using regexes with nested `*`, or `*` on successive elements which can match the same characters, can result in stellarly bad performance in some cases. You said that the actual regex you're using is bigger, so when you try to apply this to the actual regex, you may need to be careful.

Comment: @ridgerunner, when you note stuff like that on SO, you can go ahead and edit the answer (so readers are not misled). Thanks for the good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You can match any character after a backslash or any character that is not in `[abc]`:

```
(\\.|[^abc])*
```

That will match the exact same language.

I think it's actually more clear what you're intention is if you flip it around like:

```
([^abc]|\\.)*
```

Comment: This solution is simple .. and I wondered why I haven't though about that, until I realised that I asked the wrong question. But thanks anyways